# Can multiple Lync users all share their screens simultaneously?

Tags: lync

It is clear how one may share a single screen among multiple users in a Lync meeting, but is it possible for every user in a Lync meeting to share their screen simultaneously, wherein the presentation area would automatically subdivide itself into a set of small tiles so each participant can see every other screen? I am using Lync 2013.